# How to automatically convert a form with HTML link into post

Tags: posts, html, links, buddypress

I am developing a website where people can fill in forms. I would like to enable users to fill in an embedded link together with some text in a way that it is automatically converted into a post. Now I have to manually convert the links in to posts. I hope someone can help me. This is the page where people can share links: http://www.sharinghiddengems.com/share/
Hope you can help me! Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share the code for the bit you've already achieved as someone may extend it?

Comment: To be honest I did not start any code as I don't know yet where I can do this.. I was wondering maybe there is a plugin for this so that it happens automatically?    Because it is an HTML link that will not be converted.. maybe there is another way for it?